# table.insert -> remember key of inserted value

Tags: lua, lookup, lua-table

I'm inserting the value of an variable to a table and want to make sure the action succeeded.
Therefore I want to return the value, but not by the var, but from the table.

Is there a more simple way as iterating trough the table again?

Some way to remember the key of the value in the table, while it's inserted?

```
function(value)
    for _,v in pairs(theTable) do
        if v == value then
            return --(due the table already contains the value)
        end
    end
    table.insert(theTable, value)

    return -- table.[VALUE]
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
local ix = #theTable + 1
theTable[ix] = value
```

That's pretty much what `table.insert` is doing:

> As a special (and frequent) case, if we call insert without a position, it inserts the element in the last position of the array (and, therefore, moves no elements)

As a sidenote, your function is pretty inefficient; you're doing an `O(n)` "contains" check, which could be made much better if you created an index of values.